# Окончание И в слове второго склонения

Tags: склонение

*Написать статью о первопроходце космоса Юрии Гагарине.* Тростенцова, русский язык, 8 кл.

Почему в предложном падеже слово второго склонения *Юрий* имеет окончание И?

Answer (score 1):

> …Тростенцова... **8 кл.**
>
> Почему в предложном падеже слово второго склонения *Юрий* имеет
>   окончание И?

Из учебника Тростенцовой для **5-го класса**:

> Окончание ***-е*** пишется: <...> у  существительных 2-го склонения в
>   предложном падеже (кроме существительных на ***-ий, -ие***).

И далее:

> У существительных мужского рода на ***-ий*** (*санаторий, лекторий*) и
>   у существительных среднего рода на ***-ие*** (*произведение, решение*)
>   в предложном падеже единственного числа пишется на конце ***-ии.***

Answer (score 0):

Такое имя подчиняется *общей* схеме падежных окончаний второго склонения, с учётом стандартных особенностей для существительных на -**ий** и -**ие** (см. **Гербарий**):

https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/vtoroe-sklonenie-suschestvitelnyh

Удивительно, но подавляющее большинство встречающихся в сети источников этот случай игнорируют, не приводя примеров для -**ий**.